# File not found exception while reading a property file

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

```
 public boolean  WriteProperty(String key,String value){
            try{  
                    int check=0;
                    while(check == 0){
                check=1;

                Properties pro = new Properties();

                File f = new File("/properties/IxFbConfiguration.properties");
                if(!f.exists()){
                  check=0;
                  System.out.println("File not found!");
                }
                else{
                  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
                  pro.load(in);
                  System.out.print("Enter Key : ");
                  System.out.print("Enter Value : ");
                  pro.setProperty(key, value);

                  System.out.println("the property is"+pro.getProperty(key));
                 // pro.store(new FileOutputStream(str + ".properties"),null);
                  pro.store(new FileOutputStream("/properties/IxFbConfiguration.properties"),null);
                  System.out.println("Operation completly successfuly!");
                }
              }
            }
            catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
          }
```

I get file not found exception when I run this code.

I  do have a folder properties which contains the `IxFbConfiguration.properties` file.
When I hardcode the full path as
 **C:\Documents and Settings\meenakshib.DCKAP-066\Desktop\xblitzjApril18\properties\IxFbConfiguration.properties**  it works .

But I have a problem when i use the jar. 
I tried using

```
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/IxFbConfiguration.properties")
```

also but it says path not recognised.

Comment: Please give the location details of your properties file and java file from your machine in the question. Eg: C:/properties/IxFbConfiguration.properties.

Comment: Can you do an `ls /properties/IxFbConfiguration.properties` or `dir c:\properties\IxFbConfiguration.properties` ?

Comment: C:\\Documents and Settings\\meenakshib.DCKAP-066\\Desktop\\xblitzjApril18\\properties\\IxFbConfiguration.properties  THIS IS THE FILEPATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using new File(....) with a static values (path) , IMHO, is not a correct way to access a file

If you want this code to work on your IDE, AND on your server, AND for different environments, the path of the file should be :

either configurable, and an absolute path (C:/ etc on a windows env.)

or, in the classpath

Comment: But I need help since getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/IxFbConfiguration.properties") is not recognised as a path when I use the jar file

Comment: Re-reading your question, I realize that you want to write this file, so the classpath solution won't work for you.
So you might want to have a configurable path for the files your application needs (but for that we need more info, do you use spring, or is it a plain tomcat project ...?)

Comment: If u do not understand my need Kindly come on Chat...
are u there?

Comment: @Meenakshi As Samuel said, you cannot write a file that's in a jar. If you want to have a writeable properties file you HAVE TO put it on the disk where the program runs and then you HAVE TO address it with an absolute pathname.

Comment: Thanks all -- I have quit the plan of writing from the database contents to a .properties file .

Comment: No need to quit really.   
   
Attempting to write to a file inside a jar! No wonder you get a FileNotFound! This is elementary.   
   
You can first write to (create) a file and then update the jar.   

Let me know if you still have issues.